# c# - WPF closing dialog from within the dialog without a button

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog

```
SecondWindow secdWin = new SecondWindow();
secdWin.ShowDialog();
```

The above code is from my MainWindow.xaml.cs

The new window spawns and does what it's suppose to do & then i try to close it from within.

This is from my SecondWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class SecondWindow : Window
{
    public SecondWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Task initTask = new Task(() => Init());
        initTask.Start();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        server = new ServerReply();
        //.. doing stuff with the server.
        server.Reply = response.Content;
        //I want to close the SecondWindow here.
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
var w = Application.Current.Windows[0];
w.Close();
```

It doesn't work, i also tried:

```
this.Close();
```

But no matter what i do all i get is:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in WindowsBase.dll
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ... you didn't provide where are you calling Close ... I bet that you are doing this on different than UI thread

Comment: I updated my original post with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Dispatcher in your Init method. For example, like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.Close());
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have fixed the issue, i guess it was because i started a new task but never ended it? :o

Comment: It's not about ending the Task. Your Init method runs on another thread, but you can close the window only on the UI thread. And dispatcher does it in this case :)

Comment: Ohhh i see! Thank you for helping me understand why it works :D

Answer (score 0):

Run and `await` the Task in an `async` Loaded event handler:

```
public SecondWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += WindowLoaded;
}

private async void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Init());
    Close();
}
```